# Set up kafka.service and zookeeper.service in AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, systemd

On my own Ubuntu 20.04 machine, with a user `kafka`, I can successfully set up the following service files (referencing to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-20-04)):

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service`

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
ExecStart=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
```

```
[Unit]
Requires=zookeeper.service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/server.properties > ~/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1'
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then successfully start Kafka and check its status:

```
sudo systemctl start kafka
sudo systemctl status kafka
```

Now I want to set up in an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance with the same folder structure:

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service
```

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/kafka.service
```

```
[Unit]
Requires=zookeeper.service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/server.properties > /home/ubuntu/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1'
ExecStop=/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `ubuntu` is my username for AWS EC2 Ubuntu AMI according to [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html).

But when I start kafka.service, I get the following error:

```
kafka.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-06-10 18:58:26 UTC; 7s ago
    Process: 40816 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/server.properties > /home/ubuntu/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1 (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 40816 (code=exited, status=2)

Jun 10 18:58:26 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx systemd[1]: Started kafka.service.
Jun 10 18:58:26 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx sh[40816]: /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/ubuntu/kafka/kafka.log: Directory nonexistent
Jun 10 18:58:26 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx systemd[1]: kafka.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Jun 10 18:58:26 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx systemd[1]: kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Under directory `~/kafka`, I don't see the file `kafka.log`. But when setting up on my own machine, I did not encounter this error.

Am I missing anything when setting this up in AWS EC2 Ubuntu?

***More details***:
I just realized that with my user `ubuntu` access, I cannot create a folder without `sudo`. In other word:

```
$ mkdir test_folder
```

gives me `Permission denied`. I have to do:

```
$sudo mkdir test_folder
```

So, how do I modify the service files to account for this?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be doing `> /home/ubuntu/kafka/kafka.log` since the `log4j.properties` file should be creating log files. Secondly, If you installed [Confluent Platform with APT](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html#systemd-ubuntu-debian-install), these service files (and user accounts) are included

Comment: @OneCricketeer If I remove that, and have this line ```ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/server.properties > 2>&1'```, I get the following error: ```Jun 10 21:56:58 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx sh[41871]: /bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh: not found```

Comment: You don't need `/bin/sh -c` either. Look at your Zookeeper file.

Comment: So I change the line to ```ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/ubuntu/kafka/config/server.properties```. And I get this error ```kafka.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/ubuntu/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh: No such file or directory```

Comment: if the `ubuntu` user doesn't have execute permissions on the `bin` folder or the `.sh` file, then you'd get that error.

Comment: Yup. I think I found the issue. The account I am using has low permission level. Closing this question for now. Thanks for helping and all the patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with my user ubuntu access, I cannot create a folder without sudo

Unclear how you added your `ubuntu` user, but running `mkdir -p /home/ubuntu` as `ec2-user` wouldn't be correct.

You can [fix the permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604489/what-are-the-default-permissions-of-directories-in-home-desktop-downloads-etc) with these commands, but you might want to re-visit the `useradd` command options

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu
sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /home/ubuntu
```

You should also prefer to have *separate user accounts* for Kafka and Zookeeper rather than use some `ubuntu` user, which is what would happen if you use APT to install Confluent Platform, for example